# Set focus to Browser tab from the inside

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

I have two tabs running two different parts of an application. I can go into first one and send a message that is properly captured in the second tab. When that happens I want to switch a focus to the second tab. What kind of code might be to force Window obtaining the focus? A simple window.focus() is not working. Hope that's clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this would be the advertisers' dream come true, it has been blocked by all modern browsers. If you find a reliable way to do it... just wait for Google to find out and the next Chrome update will block it.

Update: It's more than just "browsers don't like that". It posses a security risk plus it's annoying UX if apps could switch from tab to tab programmatically.

Comment: But a user is deliberately navigating to a second tab. All they want is to switch to it without opening a new one.

Comment: It might be that I didn't have coffe today... with all due respect... I'm not following what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Do you have 2 tabs in a SPA? Or are you talking about the browser's tabs?

Comment: Browsers: IE, Chrome, FF.